# Web browsers: is there an equivalent to a compiler "warnings as errors" switch?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, error-handling

Like many other programmers, I consider enabling "*Treat all warning as errors*" a good practice when developing code. However, for web browsers, the standard behaviour is the exact opposite:  "*try guessing what I meant and render what seems to fit*". In order to avoid overlooking any problems , for my development environment, I'd like to set my browsers so that any **css**, **html** or **javascript** problems, instead of triggering *quirks mode* or silently logging a problem pops up a **big fat error** that I (or the *UI* designer I work with) can't miss.

Obviously, because of browser differences, I won't be able to do this for anything more than my main supported browsers - but can Chrome or Firefox or Internet Explorer 9 be set in such a way that any *fallback* mechanisms when encountering errors are disabled?

Answer (score 4):

You can define `"use strict";` at the beginning of a javascript part to use the ECMAScript5 parser, which parses stricter then the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML and CSS validators to verify content. If you dynamically generate content it's pretty easy to set it up to generate a big error message is something goes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

When I'm in development mode I use [ECMAScript 5 strict mode](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-in-firefox-4/) for javascript.

I've never found anything for CSS and HTML. I usually just run pages through validation pages, but I'd like to know if you find anything that achieves this, keep us posted!